# Chrome - moving map div back from an iframe freezes the map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome, extjs

I have a google map sitting inside my web application, I have a print button which when clicked opens an iframe, inside here I take the map from the parent and place it in the iframe, I also clone the map and put the clone into the parent so it looks the same. Inside the iframe you can move the map about etc, the user can print the map etc, my issue is when they close the iframe, I remove the cloned map and append the original map back into the parent.

In Firefox, IE and Edge I can freely move the map about after the iframe has closed, zoom in and out etc.. but in Chrome it is froze, nothing will move/zoom, if I hover over the streetview man the cursor does change though, also if I click on a hyperlink at the bottom, ie Terms of Use, this will work!

I have knocked together quickly a fiddle to show this

https://jsfiddle.net/a397981w/3/

```
// add original map again
parent.dom.appendChild(domNode);
```

When fiddle loads map is shown, click on the button below the map, the iframe will pop up with the map inside, you can move this map about, when you close the iframe and try move about inside the original map nothing will happen in Chrome.

In order to get this fiddle to work for my testing I had to run Chrome from the command line as follows, note this is only for testing purposes as I was running into cross site scripting errors with the iframe

chrome.exe --disable-web-security

Comment: is anyone viewing this able to replicate the issue in Chrome using the fiddle provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to the fact that you are listening for the ExtJS window's `destroy` event.  If you change it to listen for the `close` event, it works correctly in Chrome.

See [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a397981w/4/)

Comment: Thank you, by changing this it now works as expected in Chrome.  I never even thought that this may be affecting it, the code isn't mines but how an Ext event is causing the issue is worrisome! Do you have any ideas as to why that was causing an issue, just curious now!

Comment: I think it's related to the way the Ext JS window disposes of it's contents.  The `destroy` event happens after the window is destroyed whereas `close` happens just before it is destroyed.  You could also listen for the `beforeDestroy` event instead of `close` and that would also work.

Comment: I understand your thought process.  I probably would have picked up on this sooner had Firefox, IE or Edge not worked but the fact they did threw me off!  Thanks for the answer and explanation